# Align to right first inline-block on small devices

Tags: css

basically whats my problem, i have to divs align with inline-block, and on small devices both have width of 100% of the screen, how can i move the first div to be after the second, on small resolution, without flexbox?

```
   .main-area{
     font-size: 0px;
   }

   .left-div,
   .right-div{
   display: inline-block;

   }

   @media(max-width: 768px){
       .left-div,
       .right-div{
          width: 100%;

       }
   }
```

Comment: Use float instead of inline, and switch the DOM order around.

Comment: thanks, it worked ! :)